# How can I produce an accessible PDF using iText7's pdfhtml in C#?

Tags: c#, itext, accessibility, pdf-generation, itext7

I am attempting to produce an accessible pdf (PDF/UA 1.0) using pdfhtml add-on for iText7 (C#). Currently the html being passed as the source only contains H1 and H2 tags within the html body.  I have stripped out all of the other complexity (images, tables, and other content) of the PDF I will eventually need to produce, in order to solve the following problem.

The rendered PDF is tagged so that each heading is wrapped in both a span and p tag. Although the rendered PDF passes the Adobe Acrobat Accessibility test, it fails the accessibility testing (CommonLook PDF Validator) that is required of my US government client. As a result, my client would like us to find another software library to generate accessible PDFs, however I am not ready to give up on iText.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
void Main()
{
    string htmlSource = "<html><head><title>Test HTML to PDF iText7</title></head><body><h1>This is a heading</h1><h2>This is subheading</h2></body></html>";
    
    string appDataPath = "C:\\Users\\vagrant\\Documents\\";
    string outFileName = "TestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".pdf";
    string outputFile = appDataPath + outFileName;

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(outputFile);
    file.Directory.Create();
    
    createPdf(htmlSource, outputFile, appDataPath);
}

public void createPdf(string html, string dest, string baseUri)
{
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();

    String fonts = baseUri;
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    fontProvider.AddDirectory(fonts);
    properties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
    properties.SetBaseUri(baseUri);

    WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
    writerProperties.AddUAXmpMetadata(); //ensures that PDF/UA compatibilty is recorded

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest, writerProperties);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    
    PdfViewerPreferences preferences = new PdfViewerPreferences();
    preferences.SetDisplayDocTitle(true);
    pdf.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(preferences);
    pdf.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
    pdf.SetTagged();
    
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdf, properties);
}
```

The resulting PDF looks fine, passes Adobe Acrobat Accessibility checker, but fails the more robust CommonLook PDF Validator.  It fails with this message:
**Test: Semantically appropriate nesting
Failed: A tag of type P shouldn't be nested in H1**

Any ideas on how to prevent or override this nesting would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Searching for  [pdf/ua vs pdf/a](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf%2Fua+vs+pdf%2Fa) may be of interest.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Chapter 7: Creating PDF/UA and PDF/A documents](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-java/chapter-7-creating-pdf-ua-and-pdf-a-documents) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76145623/itextsharp-pdf-a-3-from-html-in-c-sharp/76163501#76163501

Comment: To clarify, the html source is in the code I posted above:  
<html><head><title>Test HTML to PDF iText7</title></head><body><h1>This is a heading</h1><h2>This is subheading</h2></body></html>
I have not embedded <p> or <span> tags in the <h1> tag.  It seems iText is adding them.

Comment: If that's the case, then you may consider reporting it as a bug to iText so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful comments.  I am now in touch with iText support.  They are helping with the issue.  When we work out a solution, I'll post it here.